# loop over a yaml to get a specific key value in ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a yaml file (abc.yaml) with below structure:

```
- my-container-sanity-testing:
    tier: 0
    phase: 1
    provision_windows: True
    resource_group_type: openstack
    resource_groups:
      - name: 'container_0'
        role: 'atomic'
        count: 1
        image: 'fedora-atomic-cloud-released-latest'
      - name: 'windows_0'
        role: 'ad'
        count: 1
        image: 'win-2012-r2'
```

And i have a playbook as below task.

```
-name: Get test metadata
 set_fact: 
  test_metadata="{{ lookup('file', '{{ playbook_dir }}/abc.yaml') | from_yaml }}"
```

How do i loop over the yaml assuming i already know the what specific list value (my-container-sanity-testing) and check if the list value(which is a dict) has key provision_windows: True.

Any hints on the above would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Ansible use Jinja2 template so you can use [filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html) and in this case the [`selectattr` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#selectattr):

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ test_metadata | selectattr('provision_windows') | list }}"
```

==> This will display all the elements of your `test_metadata` that has the attribute `provision_windows` set to `True`